# Bison C++ parser scaling issues

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I use Bison 3.0.4+flex2.6.0 to generate a C++ parser. Everything works fine for small files, but when things get really big (hundred of lines or really big tokens) I start getting stranger errors like:

> "fatal flex scanner internal error--no action found"

I did some debugging + research and I believe it is a stack issues, and bison manual tells to set YYINITDEPTH ....

- the problem is, where do I set the macro? I put it at the beginning of my .yy file but nothing seems to change.
- is there a way to print/show the value during runtime?

I tried to upgrade to bison 3.2 to see if this fixes the issue, but I get this error:

> "error: macro "YY_RVREF" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1"

Any idea? I am completely stuck!

```
This is what my .yy file looks like:

%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require  "3.0"
%debug
%locations
%defines
%define api.namespace {SIT}
%define parser_class_name {SIT_Parser}

%code requires{
   namespace SIT {
      class SIT_Reader;
      class SIT_Scanner;    
   }

// The following definitions is missing when %locations isn't used

#ifndef YY_NULLPTR

#if defined __cplusplus && 201103L <= __cplusplus

#define YY_NULLPTR nullptr

#else

#define YY_NULLPTR 0

#endif

#endif

#ifndef YYINITDEPTH

#define YYINITDEPTH 9000

#endif
```

Comment: "hundred of lines" isn't big by any sort of measure. Token size shouldn't matter for the Bison grammar at all. The lexer is separate. Have you tried to run your lexer standalone?

Comment: I'd try using valgrind in an attempt to see where your buffer overrun (or other similar issue) is. That error from flex shouldn't happen unless you are corrupting its internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

That problem indicates some sort of memory corruption, probably the result of Undefined Behaviour somewhere in your parsing actions (which are not visible from your question).

It's extremely unlikely to be parser stack overflow because the bison-generated parser will report any errors resulting from exceeding the capacity of the parse stack. (It calls `yyerror` with an appropriate error message, and returns 2 from the parse function.)

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
error: macro "YY_RVREF" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
```

was due to a (stupid) bug in 3.2.  Please, upgrade to 3.2.4, it addresses that bug.